# Optimized query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance

I am making  some queries on MongoDB, and i have some doubts about the most optimed query to findByID, for example in my doc i have like 10 itens but in my back-end i would like to use only 1 item, the load of mongo will load more if i have filter on my query like:

```
  mongodb.findById(req.userId,  {
          name: 0,
          date: 0,
          region: 0,
          groupName: 0,
          session: 0,
        });
```

or  these is more simple to mongodb proccess:

```
mongodb.findById(req.userId);
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you concerned about execution plans and proper indexes to find a document, or are you concerned about network latency, fetching and serialization of data?

Comment: these things: about network latency, fetching and serialization of data

Comment: since network latency, bandwidth, serialization, etc is the primary concern I would then recommend projection in the `find()` method.  Projections allow returning only the elements needed and reduce the work of returning the entire document.  This is especially beneficial when the documents are large, and there are many.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/